# Load EmberJS Fixtures Synchronously from File

Tags: json, ember.js

I am developing an EmberJS app and am relatively new to Javascript. How can I synchronously load my Ember data fixtures from a JSON file?

Comment: Why do you want to synchronously do it?

Comment: @kingpin2k I am having some issues with methods being called on Promises. There's probably a good way to do it asynchronously but for simplicity as I learn, I would prefer this just to function as if I defined the fixtures inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
model: function(){
  var payload;
    Ember.$.ajax({
       url: "url/to.json",
       async: false,
       type: "GET",
           success: function (resp) {
             payload=resp;
           },
           error: function (e) {
             console.dir(e);
           }
     });
  this.store.pushPayload('modelType', payload);
  return this.store.find('modelType');
}
```